# Rails convention for a form partial vs a list partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

What is the convention for using a partial to list an item, vs the partial show show / edit / new

For instance on an overview one would want to do:
[ app/parts/ ]
(parts/index.html.erb)

```
<h1> Parts and stuff! </h1>
<table>
# headers and such
<%= render :partial => @parts %>
</table>
# calls _part to make a list, usually the 3 most important things
```

Then we have something like
[ app/parts/new ]
(parts/new.html.erb)

```
# what is the convention for the partial here? 
# Said partial would be used for new / edit
```

I know you can specify render :partial => "path/to/partial", but I was hoping for a resource based route to want a partial by some conventional name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually _form_part or _part depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't really have conventions for partial names. Conventions are for RESTful template names for controller actions, i.e., index, new, show, edit. The actions create, update, and destroy use redirects rather than rendering anything directly.

Partials serve two purposes: one is when you want to avoid duplication, i.e., for new/edit forms. The other is when you want to update pages with AJAX. Naming conventions are basically up to you, just try to be consistent.

But routes (resource-based or otherwise) don't really apply to partials; they're handled by the template engine, not the dispatcher.

If you'd like to see generators that effectively use partials in action, try Ryan Bates' `nifty_generators` gem.

You can find it here: https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

Comment: I disagree. The most obvious counter point be _partial.html.foo. Getting rails to render a partial that doesn't start with `_` is quite a bit of extra work. Similarly, you can use shorthands such as render :partial => object.has_many_relations. and it will look for "_has_many_relation.html"